# Open ,csv file in backgound using vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, module, copy

I want to access data from a .csv file in background without opening it.

My code works well but I don’t want  ”FiletoOpen” to physically open.
It now opens, has its data read, places it all in the “Raw_Data” worksheet, and then immediately closes.

This causes a flicker, even though I have  Application.ScreenUpdating set to False.  Is there any way to open it in background (Not physically)?  Much appreciated.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FiletoOPen = directory & NewestFile     ‘a .csv file is defined earlier in the code

Workbooks.OpenText FiletoOPen, ReadOnly = True, __
DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True

Set wbTextImport = ActiveWorkbook

Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw_Data")
wsMaster.Cells.Clear

wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A1")
wbTextImport.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
here
```

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the source data, you *might* consider reading the file into memory using VBA and then parse it. It's not really recommended when Excel's built in reader/parser is so good, but if you're really bothered by the flicker then it would certainly resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this, assuming:

- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library present on device
- CSV file stored in UTF-8 encoding
- each row of CSV data ends with vbNewLine
- each item of CSV data is separated with comma
- no vbNewLines or commas elsewhere in the CSV data

```
Sub GetCSV(wks As Worksheet, sFilePath As String)
    Dim asLines() As String, i As Long
    asLines = Split(ReadTextFile(sFilePath), vbNewLine) ' assumes each row of data is delimited with a vbNewLine
    For i = 0 To UBound(asLines) - 1
        Dim v As Variant
        v = Split(asLines(i), ",") ' assumes each item of data (within a row) is delimited with a comma
        wks.Range(wks.Cells(i + 1, 1), wks.Cells(i + 1, UBound(v) + 1)) = v ' assumes you want the first item of data in cell "A1"
    Next i
End Sub


Function ReadTextFile(sFilePath As String) As String
    ' requires Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") ' an ADODB.Stream object
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Mode = 3 ' 3 = adModeReadWrite
        .Type = 2 ' 2 = adTypeText
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile sFilePath
        ReadTextFile = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Which you would then use like this, for example:

```
GetCSV wbTextImport.Worksheets(1), directory & NewestFile
```